# Кубарем катится.

Tags: этимология

Какое интересное слово "кубарем"! А каково его происхождение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ушаков:

> КУБА́РЬ, кубаря, твор. кубарём (ср.
> нареч. кубарем), муж. Детская игрушка
> в форме шара или цилиндра (обычно
> деревянного) с приделанной к нему
> остроконечной ножкой, на которой он
> вертится подобно волчку.

Ожегов даёт слово КУБАРЬ в этом значении как устаревшее (другое значение - "маленький кубик", помечено как "прост.").

Вряд ли наречие **кубарем** произошло от **куб** - "тело кубической формы"; более вероятно всё-таки от **кубарь** - "волчок" (в форме шара или цилиндра).

**Кубарь**, в свою очередь, происходит, как указывает Фасмер, "скорее всего от куб, ку́бовина" (**куб** здесь, видимо, в значении "сосуд для перегонки жидкостей в форме шара или цилиндра").

Answer (score 4):

У меня в детстве в разговорном  языке слов "юла" и "волчок" не было. Все, что теперь можно назвать юлой, мы, детвора (да и взрослые), называли - "кубарь". Местность наша - весьма консервативная во всех смыслах. Если судить по этому признаку, то кубарь в русском языке, вероятно, имеет гораздо более ранее происхождение, чем его современно понимаемые синонимы. Свидетельствую не по литературным источникам, а по живому "великорусскому".

Answer (score 1):

У "Куба" два значения. Одно из них - большой сосуд, емкость, перегонный чан - вполне себе русское. Сравните "Кубок", "Кубышка". Кубарь - человек, изготовляющий такие кубы. Или как-то с ним связанный: владеющий кубом, работающий на нём. Вполне вероятно, что название волчка произошло от него.

Так или примерно так я понимаю Фасмера.

Не совсем ясна, правда, мотивация. Почему волчок связали с таким кубом? Кстати, есть ещё "кубик" в значении "игральная кость". Не уверен, что от математического значения. И вот он-то, этот кубик, во-первых родственен волчку (по функциям), во-вторых катится вполне себе замечательно.

Comment: @tmp, ну по геометрической форме же (мотивация)! Куб - сосуд *в форме шара или цилиндра*. Кубарь - детская игрушка *в форме шара или цилиндра*...

Comment: Возникает вопрос, почему "куб" в форме шара или цилиндра созвучен "кубу" кубической формы? Ясно, что последнее слово пришло из европейских языков. Но было ли оно независимым? Может, оба слова являются потомками какого-то смысла, связанного с формой, но потом разошлись в разных языках?

Comment: @DocentI, когда-то, может, они и были родственными. На странице http://slovari.yandex.ru/%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B1/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/ можно посмотреть подробнее...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, кубарь имеет отношение к слову "кувыркаться". Поэтому "кубарем" - это "кувыркаясь"

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, кубарь - детская игрушка, которую катали. Но откуда ее название -не знаю. Вряд ли родственно  слову "куб", оно все-таки не русское.

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо всем участникам. Вы помогаете глубже нырнуть в это бездонное море - наш язык.